# how to get a list of database in quick.db?

Tags: node.js, database, discord, discord.js, quick.db

I want to get a list of a key inside my database I use `` db.set(`fuel_${car}`, amount of fuel) `` and then I want to get a list of all cars fuel, here is my code :

```
/*set the fuel of lol9*/
client.on('message', async message => {

if(message.content === 'db') {

  const m = await db.get('fuel');
  message.channel.send(`${m}`);
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick.db documentation states:

> ## .all() -> array
>
> This function returns the entire active table as an array.
>
> ```js
> await db.all()
> // -> [Array]
> ```

This being said, you could do this:

```js
let carFuelArray = [];
await db.all().then(array => {
   array.forEach(element, => {
      if(element.startWith("fuel_")) {
         // if you want to log "fuel_{car}"
         carFuelArray.push(element)
         // if you want to log the "fuel_{car}" key value
         carFuelArray.push(db.get(element))
      }
   })
})
```

Comment: it says db.all(...).then is not a function

Comment: @ExpensiveSalt you can assign db.all() to a variable and then do the .forEach() with that variable